# How to get a List<anonymous type> generated by Linq outside of an using statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Got a query using the using statement, which means once it ends the object created gets disposed.

```
using (Context context = new())
{
    var records = context.PoRecords
        .Join(
            context.PoStatuses,
            record => record.PoStatus,
            status => status.Id,
            (record, status) => new
            {
                record.PoNumber,
                record.PrNumber,
                Status = status.Name,
            }
        ).ToList();
}
```

How can I get that list outside of that using?
What I think I have to do is create a custom class for that query, declare a list of that type outside the using and fill it with the contents of the query, I've done that when I query the whole table, but, since this is joining tables I can't just declare `List<CustomType> records = ...querywithjoins...` because the list Linq is returning is of an anonymous type. I'd have to do that outside the using, kind of like this:

```
List<CustomType> records;

using (Context context = new()){
    records = TheWholeQuery.ToList();
}
```

Another way I thought of doing it was, since I am listing the results of the query in a list view with a foreach, creating new objects of the custom type and add them into the new list, but, that means I'd have to iterate through each and every query I do, and I don't intend to do that everytime.

Is there a way to do this? Or a workaround??

Comment: You could also remove the using statement and dispose of the context after obtaining your records.

Comment: you could also use the syntax `using Context context = new()` and it will be disposed when out of scope (but not form a scope where your `records` goes away). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: @hijinxbassist Yeah, might end up doing that, it's just that I like using the using statement for closing connections. And it's pretty useful when creating generic methods for handling db connections. But if there really isn't another way of doing it I'm just gonna do as you say. Thanks for the comment!!

Comment: The solution to this is simple: *don't use the `using` statement.*  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359667/is-it-ok-to-create-an-entity-framework-datacontext-object-and-dispose-it-in-a-us#:~:text=Although%20the%20DbContext%20implements%20IDisposable,the%20database%20connection%20for%20you.

Comment: Thank you @RobertHarvey! I've been told so many times to never forget to close connections that I just started using ```using``` religiously. Had a read to a couple of the articles you linked on that answer. Interesting stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tuple if you don't want to define a class although I have found in these circumstances it's usually ends up being easier to just define the class.

```
List<Tuple<int, int, string>> records = null; 

using (Context context = new())
{
    records = context.PoRecords
        .Join(
            context.PoStatuses,
            record => record.PoStatus,
            status => status.Id,
                    (record, status) => new Tuple<int, int, string>(
                        record.PoNumber,
                        record.PrNumber,
                        status.Name
                    )
        ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yep, this totally worked! Using ```List<CustomType> records = null;``` and ```...(record, status) => new CustomType(...``` in this case, since I found it easier to just create the class. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If u don't want to remove using statement u can just convert your list with anonymous type to list of 'CustomType'

so..

```
List<CustomType> records;
using (Context context = new())
{
    records = context.PoRecords
    .Join(
        context.PoStatuses,
        record => record.PoStatus,
        status => status.Id,
        (record, status) => new CustomType()
        {
            PoNumber = record.PoNumber,
            PrNumber = record.PrNumber,
            Status = status.Name,
        }
    ).ToList();
```

}